# Reduce application switcher clutter?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, application-switcher

How do you make Gnome's application switcher only show the applications for the current workspace?

That's how it used to work in 20.04. I upgraded to 22.04 and now the switcher shows all applications everywhere, which defeats the purpose of workspaces and makes switching very slow and cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Settings -> Multitasking` there are two options under `Application Switching` to set whatever behavior you want for different workspaces and also for different monitors.

Comment: That option is indeed there, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Sometimes, it even seems to revert and doesn't save. Do I need to reboot or something after enabling it?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be right, it does not have any effect on the alt-tab switching interface for me either (on 22.04.3 LTS). It only seems to affect what icons are shown on the taskbar. For me the switcher only shows apps from the current workspace regardless of the setting (which is the opposite of you!). I can't explain why or where the problem lies. I have fixed number of workspaces, 2 monitors and workspaces on primary display only.